# Trouble importing from two classes in different files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am having trouble importing instance from two different classes that reside in two different files. The two files look like:

**Filename: doublemap.py**

```
import stops
class DoubleMap(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.url = "https://someurl"

mapInstance = DoubleMap()
```

**Filename: stops.py**

```
from doublemap import DoubleMap
import urllib.request as urllib2
import json

class Bus_stops(DoubleMap):
    def __init__(self):
       self.stops_maps = {}
       self.stops_URL = DoubleMap().url+"stops"

    def fetch_details(self):
       json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(self.stops_URL)
       data = json.load(json_obj)
       for stops_details in data:
          self.stops_maps[stops_details['id']] = {
            stops_details['name'],
            stops_details['description'],
            stops_details['lat'],
            stops_details['lon'],
            stops_details['buddy'],
            # stops_details['fields']
        }
     return self.stops_maps


temp = Bus_stops()
print(temp.fetch_details())
```

Doubts:

1. How can I use the value that is returned from stops.py by fetchdetails function into doublemap.py and store in some variable?
2. When I run doublemap.py it shows the value that is printed in stops.py but if I run stops.py, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "Doublemap/DoubleMap/stops.py", line 1, in <module>
>   from doublemap import DoubleMap
> File "Doublemap/DoubleMap/doublemap.py", line 1, in <module>
>   import stops
> File "Doublemap/DoubleMap/stops.py", line 1, in <module>
>   from doublemap import DoubleMap
> ImportError: cannot import name 'DoubleMap'
> ```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file name as `__init__.py` with the same directory with your both scripts.

and your project directory structure should be like:

```
pro/
   __init__.py
   doublemap.py
   stops.py
```

By the way, you could do the related import at your header.

> The primary use of **init**.py is to initialize Python packages. The
>   easiest way to demonstrate this is to take a look at the structure of
>   a standard Python module.

your code in the `doublemap.py`:

```
import stops
```

You should import `stops` at the begin of `doublemap.py` if you don't need it.

[For more](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html)

Comment: But I want to keep the scripts in two different files.

Comment: @AdityaKushwah I have review your code, and you have `python relative import`

Answer (score 0):

**in Stops.py** call it like this

```
from doublemap import DoubleMap

k = DoubleMap()
print(k.Method())
```

**in doublemap.py** use method to return the variable

```
class DoubleMap(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.url = "https://someurl"

   def Method(self):
      return self.url
```

Answer (score 0):

Import cycles are evil. Don't.

In addition you do not need it here: `doublemap.py` has no reason to import `stops.py`:

Filename: doublemap.py

```
# import stops # NO IMPORT CYCLE!
class DoubleMap(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.url = "https://someurl"

mapInstance = DoubleMap()
```

Filename: stops.py

```
from doublemap import DoubleMap
import urllib.request as urllib2
import json

class Bus_stops(DoubleMap):
    def __init__(self):
       self.stops_maps = {}
       self.stops_URL = DoubleMap().url+"stops"

    def fetch_details(self):
       json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(self.stops_URL)
       data = json.load(json_obj)
       for stops_details in data:
          self.stops_maps[stops_details['id']] = {
            stops_details['name'],
            stops_details['description'],
            stops_details['lat'],
            stops_details['lon'],
            stops_details['buddy'],
            # stops_details['fields']
        }
     return self.stops_maps


temp = Bus_stops()
print(temp.fetch_details())
```